# How to add a line break in oldschool javascript div

Tags: javascript

I have to alter the following code somehow to add line breaks to the labels on the buttons generated by AddRemoteButtonText. Tried everything I found on this site, but nothing worked yet (most probably because I`m just starting out coding javascript). Mostly tried adding another variable to the function and then implementing it by "\n" .

```
    var size = 20;
var repeat_timer;

function AddRemoteButtonText(num, posx, posy, wx, wy, color, label, remote, command, initial_delay, repeat_delay) 
{
    document.write('<div id="' + num + '" class="button ' + color + '" style="position:absolute; top:' + posy + 'px; left:' + posx + 'px; height:' + wy + 'px; width:' + wx + 'px; line-height: ' + wy + 'px;" align="center">' + label + '</div>');
    document.getElementById(num).onmouseup = function () { SendIRCommand (num,remote,command,initial_delay,repeat_delay); EndSendCommand (num) };
    document.getElementById(num).onmouseleave = function () { EndSendCommand (num) };
}

    }
};
```

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: document.write is document.wrong. Use something more modern and less prone to doing confusing things. This function tries to write to the current document. If the document has already been processed, the document will be replaced with a blank one with your argument. You don't want that; use the proper DOM methods instead. You also shouldn't have two functions with the exact same name in the same scope. Also, having more than one element with a particular ID is invalid HTML.

Comment: Would love to do that, but I'm not advanced enough - it's someone else's program that I mostly don't understand.. I just need line breaks one the buttons :)
It's a javascript code

Comment: Just use CSS to make those `label,button,input[type=button]{ display:block; }`. Of course, make the CSS more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Add `'<br>'` like in the below example

```
document.write(variable +'<br/>'+ variable2);
```

Comment: To clarify: this works because `</br>` is interpreted as the HTML tag "Line Break". As such it would **not** work for JavaScript scripts that output to the console rather than a web page (in these scripts it **would** work with `\r\n`), but it does of course work perfectly well in this use case.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, neither '<br/>' nor '</br>'. I added a new "argument" to the function after 'label' and it even broke the function
`function AddRemoteButtonText(num, posx, posy, wx, wy, color, label, labelnew, remote, command, initial_delay, repeat_delay) 
{
    document.write('<div id="' + num + '" class="button ' + color + '" style="position:absolute; top:' + posy + 'px; left:' + posx + 'px; height:' + wy + 'px; width:' + wx + 'px; line-height: ' + wy + 'px;" align="center">' + label + '</br>' + labelnew +'</div>');`

Comment: @Finalis did you try what Bjonnfesk suggested? using \r\n

Comment: Just tried it with the same result, only the first line with "label" is shown, none of the rest and the function does not work anymore.. :( `function AddRemoteButtonText(num, posx, posy, wx, wy, color, label, labelnew, remote, command, initial_delay, repeat_delay) 
{
    document.write('<div id="' + num + '" class="button ' + color + '" style="position:absolute; top:' + posy + 'px; left:' + posx + 'px; height:' + wy + 'px; width:' + wx + 'px; line-height: ' + wy + 'px;" align="center">' + label + '\r\n' + labelnew +'</div>');`

Comment: Could you use something like Chrome's developer tools to figure out precisely what the inner HTML of the resulting <div> is, in both the `\r\rn` (which **shouldn't** work on web pages unless wrapped in <pre> tags), and the `<br>` case?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it like this (simplified for example purposes):

```js
var i = 0;
var aboveLineBreak;
var belowLineBreak;

function AddRemoteButtonText() {
  console.log(i);
  //define some text to print to the button
  aboveLineBreak = "above br" + i;
  belowLineBreak = "below br" + i;
  //create a button object
  var btn = document.createElement("DIV");
  
  //add our text, including the line break, to the button
  btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode(aboveLineBreak));
  btn.appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
  btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode(belowLineBreak));
  //define our button's CSS style
  btn.setAttribute("class", "button red");
  //to set the position, do:
  //btn.style.position = "absolute";
  //btn.style.top = whatever;
  //and so on...
  //add listeners if needed...
  btn.onmouseup = function () { console.log("foo"); };
  //finally add the button to the document's body and increment i
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
  i++;
}
```

```css
.button {
  width: 33%;
  height: 45px;
}

.red {
  background-color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <button onClick="AddRemoteButtonText();"> Add Remote Button Text </button>
</body>

</html>
```

Not the most beautiful buttons, but if you simply substitute my CSS with your own you should have a working line break. If not, we will need you to post your CSS so we can have a look at it.

Comment: As an aside, may I ask why a <div> and not an <a> or a <button> tag for the button?